# IntelliJ compile warning for Groovy code is wrong

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, warnings, option-type

```
Optional<BigDecimal> maybeConvertStringToBigDecimal(Optional<String> string) {
        string.flatMap {
            try {
                return Optional.of(new BigDecimal(it))
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error "Exception: ${e.message}\n\n${e.stackTrace}"
                return Optional.<BigDecimal> empty()
            }
        }
    }
```

This code compiles just fine but IntelliJ shows a red warning that

> Cannot return 'Optional<U>' from method returning
>   'Optional<BigDecimal>'

I think it is clear that there is always Optional<BigDecimal> returned. What can be done to get rid of the warning? Is this an IntelliJ issue or is there an issue with the code?

Comment: Thanks for reporting on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-198057

Comment: Still broken, I wonder what my license $$$ are spent on, certainly not this